# Get average from input radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input, radio-button

I want to get the average by input radio button value.
I have a form with 3x 10 radio fields counting from 1 to 10.
Now I want to calculate the average, so you get a final score.
I get it working with a text field, but I don't know how to do it with radio buttons checked.

This is my javascript:

```
$('.beoordeling').keyup(function () {

var total = 0,
    valid_labels = 0,
    average;

$('.beoordeling').each(function () {
    var val = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
    if (!isNaN(val)) {
        valid_labels += 1;
        total += val;
    }
});

console.log(total)

average = total / valid_labels;
$('.eindstand').val(average);
});
```

I have created a jsfiddle with how I have it now.
http://jsfiddle.net/Q2MEq/

Comment: where are the radio buttons? I dont see any

Comment: so where are your radio buttons?

Comment: @AnoopJoshi I still have text fields, but that should be radio buttons.

Comment: Can you post the desired html structure?

Comment: When I use radio buttons it does not work, the javascript that grabs all values ​​and not the checked ones

Comment: but provide your desired html so that we can help

Comment: Sir ,i request you, Can you please tell me Do you want to calculate AVG based on radio button value ,or id? Please tell me if you respect Answerer.

Comment: html: http://pastebin.com/WrEzPXtP js: http://pastebin.com/2Yq0iJv9

Comment: try this : http://jsfiddle.net/WN95r/

Answer (score 1):

**[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q2MEq/1/)**

---

Check this code.

```
$('.beoordeling').change(function () {

    var total = 0,
        valid_labels = 0,
        average;

    $('.beoordeling:checked').each(function () {
        var val = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
        if (!isNaN(val)) {
            valid_labels += 1;
            total += val;
        }
    });

    console.log(total)

    average = total / valid_labels;
    $('.eindstand').val(average);
});
```

- Use `change` events in case of inputs like radio and not keyup.
- use `:checked` selector to get selected radio buttons only.

Answer (score 1):

See for this you need to have `radio` buttons with different `name` attributes or without it, and then you can change to this:

```
    $(':radio').change(function () {
    var total = 0,
        valid_labels = 0,
        average;
    $(':checked').each(function () {
        var val = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
        if (!isNaN(val)) {
            valid_labels += 1;
            total += val;
        }
    });
    console.log(total)
    average = total / valid_labels;
    $('.eindstand').val(average);
});
```

---

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Q2MEq/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Please check this

```
$('.beoordeling').keyup(function () {

    var total = 0,
        valid_labels = 0,
        average;

    $('.beoordeling').each(function () {
        var val = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
        if (!isNaN(val)) {
            valid_labels += 1;
            total += val;
        }
    });

    console.log(total)

    average = total / valid_labels;
    $('.eindstand').val(average);
});
```

Demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mail2asik/xW8nh/3/)

Answer (score -1):

You can determine whether or not a radio button is checked with ".checked"

```
document.getElementById("radio_1").checked
```

... will return true if the button is checked, false otherwise.

Comment: Please provide full answer with fiddle.